# CSS navigation hover dropdown speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two problems regarding my code:

1. Navigation menu when you hover "Naslovna" drops down and back up too fast, I would like to reduce the time preferably using CSS.
2. In the jsbin attachment you can see in the middle of the website cubes when you mouse over them they pull up and display text, I have a problem with them because once they are show they pull down wich is good but they dont display text while dropping down.

Can you help me resolve these bugs, here is jsbin debugging link:

http://jsbin.com/zabuvu/1/edit

Regards,
Magix

Comment: Please include your code here instead of just linking to jsbin code; it's a rule.

Comment: Also your images are not displaying....

Comment: Sorry for not displaying code but when i format it corectly it still wont allow me to post it for some reason, also the images are not important i just posted relative code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this (hides the text when it goes down)

```
.perpic .hovereffect  {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

and change this selector

```
.perpic:hover .hovereffect p {
   ...
}
```

to (the style always stays, before it was activated on 'hover' only)

```
.perpic .hovereffect p {
   ...
}
```

But now there is a duplicate selector that came before it. You can remove altogether or just the property

```
display: none;
```

from

```
.perpic .hovereffect p
```

Transition properties in `.perpic .hovereffect` control speed of going down, while `.perpic:hover .hovereffect` transition properties control the up speed. Change the seconds to whatever you like

```
transition: all 1.5s ease 0s;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, I decided to remove the selector instead of just property, do you have any idea for the navigation bar animation?